# How can write this in a better way?

Tags: python, try-catch

Do you have any idea to write this more cleanly ? I am using a module which have several function on it but the syntax is the same like you can see.

```
import browser_cookie3
site = "SOME WEBSITE"
cookies = []
try:
    cookies.append(str(browser_cookie3.chrome(domain_name=site)))
except:
    pass
try:
    cookies.append(str(browser_cookie3.edge(domain_name=site)))
except:
    pass
try:
    cookies.append(str(browser_cookie3.firefox(domain_name=site)))
except:
    pass
try:
    cookies.append(str(browser_cookie3.brave(domain_name=site)))
except:
    pass
try:
    cookies.append(str(browser_cookie3.opera(domain_name=site)))
except:
    pass
try:
    cookies.append(str(browser_cookie3.vivaldi(domain_name=site)))
except:
    pass
try:
    cookies.append(str(browser_cookie3.chromium(domain_name=site)))
except:
    pass
```

Comment: Looks like a job for a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a list of the browser names as strings you can then use `getattr` to get the function from the module dynamically:

```py
import browser_cookie3
site = "SOME WEBSITE"
cookies = []

browsers = [
    "chrome",
    "edge",
    "firefox",
    "brave",
    "opera",
    "vivaldi",
    "chromium",
]

for browser in browsers:
    try:
        cookies.append(str(getattr(browser_cookie3, browser)(domain_name=site)))
    except:
        pass
```

Note that you should specify the exact error to suppress: `except AttributeError:` for example. If you catch *all* errors like you are, it will make it difficult to debug later if there's an unexpected error